# Cannot read property 'sky' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display an Icon and use parameteres that API gives me back. Whenever I try to do it, I get undefined. Tryed to do this like this :

```
import React from 'react';
import './WeatherBox.css'
import { Icons } from '../../icons';


const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    let day = days[d.getDay()];
    let date = d.getDate();
    let month = months[d.getMonth()];
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
}

const WeatherBox = ({result}) => {

        return (
            <div className="locationDate">
                <span>{result.location}</span>
                <span>{dateBuilder(new Date())}</span>
                <span>{result.temp}°C</span> 
                {/* <span>{Icons.Clouds}</span> */}
                <span>{result ? Icons.result.sky : null}</span>
            </div>
        )

}

export default WeatherBox;
```

`result.sky` is variable that API gives me back, something like "Clouds" "Sunny" etc. that's how my icons are named and i want to display them when API is loaded. Condition I used doesn't work, and It wants to display before API is even returned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you are importing Icons from a file, but you are saying it's from an API? You need to post the code that is calling the api

Comment: It looks more like `Icons.result` is undefined. What is included in `Icons`?

Comment: `result.sky` may be the variable that your API sets, but `Icons.result.sky` is an altogether different thing.

Comment: Icons are not from API, it's from different file where i download all svg images to one index.js and then import it to WeatherBox component. From API i get `result.sky`. It gives me something like "Clouds", so as my svg file is named. I want to display them by 
 `Icons.Name` and the name here is what API gives me back. `(result.sky)`

Comment: This `Icons.result.sky` is what throws the error correct?

Comment: Yes, `result.sky` gives me respond, but whenever I try to assaign it to Icons it gives me undefined error. I thought it's because It tries to display before API is even returned.

Comment: Understandable. Need the code where you are making api call and code where you are passing the returned api result to the WeatherBox component.

Comment: So u want me to paste my whole two components or just lines where I declare "sky" and line in main component by which I send this to WeatherBox as props?

Comment: Have you tried something like `<span>{Icons && Icons.result && result ? Icons.result.sky : null}</span>`?

Comment: The answer is I tried to refer to Icons wrong. Instead of using `Icons.result.sky`, i had to do It like `Icons[result.sky]`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I tried to refer to Icons wrong. Instead of using Icons.result.sky, i had to do It like Icons[result.sky].